# Antd inputNumber focus delete formatter , blur add formatter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, onfocus

When I use Antd InputNumber,  I want to focused it to display {value}, and blur it to display `{value}%`

But I have encountered a problem, when I focused it to display `{value}%` , but blur it display value, not `{value}%`, again, just display value

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-88e1lk?file=demo.tsx)

```
const App = () => {
  const [focus, setFocus] = React.useState(false);

  const changeFocus = (newFocus) => {
    setFocus(newFocus);
  };

  const props = (newFocus) => {
    return {
      formatter: newFocus ? (value) => value : (value) => `${value}%`,
      parser: newFocus ? (value) => value : (value) => value!.replace('%', ''),
    };
  };

  return (
    <Space>
      <InputNumber
        onFocus={() => {
          console.log('===focus===');
          changeFocus(true);
        }}
        onBlur={() => {
          changeFocus(false);
        }}
        defaultValue={100}
        min={0}
        max={100}
        onChange={onChange}
        {...props(focus)}
      />
    </Space>
  );
};
```